# ¿Por qué se puede usar el operador de Ámbito (::) en un método no es estático?

Tags: php

Porque no surge ningun problema si no eh instanciado la clase y use directamente el doble puntos "::" para llamar directo a un metodo sin la clase ser instanciada, pero el metodo no tiene el static y aun asi funciona y muestra lo que tengo en template.php, y se supone que el simbolo :: es para usar metodos estaticos o.o

```
** Carpetas con los archivos **

┌Controllers
├──contTemplate.php
|
├views
├──template.php
|
└index.php
```

--contTemplate.php

```
<?php
class Plantilla{
    public function getPlantilla(){
        include "views/template.php";
    }
}
```

--index.php

```
<?php

require "controllers/contTemplate.php";
Plantilla::getPlantilla();
```

Comment: Documentación de PHP: [Operador de Resolución de Ámbito](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) _...el doble dos-puntos, es un token que permite acceder a elementos estáticos, constantes, y sobrescribir propiedades o métodos de una clase._ Para acceder a métodos estáticos no hay de otra que usar `::`, Para métodos 'normales' es válido, aunque crea más confusión usarse de esta manera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ¿Por qué se puede?

El que todavía hoy se pueda hacer esto es debido a querer salvar la compatibilidad de PHP con versiones anteriores.

Hay que tener en cuenta que el [modelo de objetos](https://www.php.net/oop5) fue introducido en PHP 5, y con él se incluyó la palabra `static` en el lenguaje. Significa que en PHP 4 no se podía diferenciar entre un método de objeto y la función global escrita como un método de clase estática. Por tanto, ambos funcionaban.

PHP ha ido aclarándose con el problema de `static`, y desde PHP 5.1.3, se acordó lanzar una advertencia del tipo `E_STRICT` ante este uso (indebido realmente), y desde PHP 5.6 se cambió a una advertencia del tipo `E_DEPRECATED`, y este uso pasó a ser parte de las [características obsoletas del lenguaje](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration56.deprecated.php).

De hecho, aunque aparentemente no pasa nada, `Plantilla::getPlantilla()` eleva una advertencia `E_DEPRECATED` desde PHP 5.6:

> ... PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Plantilla::getPlantilla()
> should not be called statically in /...

El Manual es claro al respecto:

> Los métodos llamados desde un contexto incompatible ahora están
> obsoletos, generando errores `E_DEPRECATED` en lugar de `E_STRICT`
> cuando son invocados. El soporte para dichas llamadas será eliminado
> en una futura versión de PHP.

### ¿Debo seguir haciéndolo porque el código  no falla gravemente?

No rotundo. Lo que empezó permitiéndose a causa de la compatibilidad, terminará dando problemas tarde o temprano si no se corrige, a causa de la misma compatibilidad. El Manual lo dice claro: ***el soporte para dichas llamadas será eliminado en una futura versión de PHP***. Significa que en un futuro este uso podría convertirse en un **error fatal** que sí va a detener el código. Por tanto, **esta práctica no debe solamente evitarse**, sino que hay que ir **corrigiendo el código, donde quiera que se haya llevado a cabo**.

---

#### Enlaces

- [*Calling non-static method with double-colon(::)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3754786/5587982)

Comment: Buen punto. Estas dudas si se indicará la versión de PHP que están usando, o tuvieran los errores activados durante el desarrollo, prácticamente se resuelven solas.
PHP 5.6 salio ya hace 6 años y lleva 2 deprecado. Mucho más PHP 5.5 y versiones anteriores. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP