# conectar() should not be called statically in C:\wamp64\www\frontend\modelos\plantilla.modelo.php on line 9

Tags: php

> Deprecated: Non-static method Conexion::conectar() should not be called statically in C:\wamp64\www\frontend\modelos\plantilla.modelo.php on line 9
> <!====================================================
> ESTA ES LA LINEA QUE NO ME CONECTA
> =========================================

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloPlantilla{

    static public function mdlEstiloPlantilla($tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();

        $stmt -> close();

    }

}
```

==========================================

```js
/*=============================================
CABEZOTE
=============================================*/

$("#btnCategorias").click(function(){

    if(window.matchMedia("(max-width:767px)").matches){

        $("#cabezote").after($("#categorias").slideToggle("fast"))

    }else{

        $("#cabezote").after($("#categorias").slideToggle("fast"))
        
    }

        
})
```

```css
/*=============================================
GLOBAL
=============================================*/

*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Ubunt', sans-serif;
}

ul, ol{
    padding:0px;
}

a:visited, a:link, a:focus, a:hover, a:active{
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.barraSuperior{
    background:black;
}

.barraSuperior a{
    color:white;
}

.backColor, .backColor a{
    background:#47bac1;
    color:white;
}

.fondoBreadcrumb{
    margin-bottom:0px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

/*=============================================
REDES SOCIALES
=============================================*/

.redSocial{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:30px;
}

/*FACEBOOK*/

.facebookBlanco{
    color:white;
}

.facebookNegro{
    color:black;
}

.facebookColor{
    color:white;
    background:#46639f;
}

/*YOUTUBE*/

.youtubeColor{
    color:white;
    background:#d6513e;
}

.youtubeBlanco{
    color:white;
}

.youtubeNegro{
    color:black;
}

/*TWITTER*/

.twitterColor{
    color:white;
    background:#0ab2e6;
}

.twitterBlanco{
    color:white;
}

.twitterNegro{
    color:black;
}

/*GOOGLE PLUS*/

.googleColor{
    color:white;
    background:#d71617;
}

.googleBlanco{
    color:white;
}

.googleNegro{
    color:black;
}

/*INSTAGRAM*/

.instagramColor{
    color:white;
    background:linear-gradient(45deg, #fca925, #ee1d5f,  #6350a2);

}

.instagramBlanco{
    color:white;
}

.instagramNegro{
    color:black;
}

/*=============================================
ERROR 404
=============================================*/

.error404{
    color:#333;
}

/*=============================================
SCROLL UP
=============================================*/
#scrollUp{
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(../img/plantilla/flecha.jpg);
}


/*=============================================
ESCRITORIO GRANDE (LG revisamos en 1366px en adelante)
=============================================*/

@media (min-width:1200px){

    .col-lg-0{
        display: none;
    }

    .error404 h1{
        font-size:300px;
        text-shadow:8px 8px 1px #dadada;
    }

}

/*=============================================
ESCRITORIO MEDIANO O TABLET HORIZONTAL (MD revisamos en 1024px)
=============================================*/

@media (max-width:1199px) and (min-width:992px){

    .col-md-0{
        display: none;
    }

    .error404 h1{
        font-size:200px;
        text-shadow:6px 6px 1px #dadada;
    }

}

/*=============================================
ESCRITORIO PEQUEÑO O TABLET VERTICAL (SM revisamos en 768px)
=============================================*/

@media (max-width:991px) and (min-width:768px){

    .col-sm-0{
        display: none;
    }

    .error404 h1{
        font-size:150px;
        text-shadow:4px 4px 1px #dadada;
    }

}

/*=============================================
MOVIL (XS revisamos en 320px)
=============================================*/

@media (max-width:767px){

    .col-xs-0{
        display: none;
    }

    .error404 h1{
        font-size:75px;
        text-shadow:2px 2px 1px #dadada;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <meta name="title" content="Tienda Virtual">

    <meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam accusantium enim esse eos officiis sit officia">

    <meta name="keyword" content="Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisicing, elit, Quisquam, accusantium, enim, esse">

    <title>Danusky Kids</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/css/plugins/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu|Ubuntu+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/css/plantilla.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/css/cabezote.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/css/productos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/css/slide.css"> 
    
    <script scr="vistas/js/plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="vistas/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <!--======================================
 CABEZOTE
 ========================================-->
 <?php
include "modulos/cabezote.php"

?>
<script href="vistas/js/cabezote.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega solo el código relevante Al problema, por ejemplo tú css no tiene nada que ver lo mismo que el JS y el HTML

Comment: Edita y agrega la clase de dónde invocas a este método `conectar`

Comment: Considera [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la definición clase `Conexion`. PD: Creo que el mensaje de error es bastante claro `conectar no es un método estatico`.

Comment: Hola @Jonathan. Este mensaje `Conexion::conectar() should not be called statically` significa que la función no ha sido declarada como `public static function conectar() {}`, de allí el error de que no se puede llamar estáticamente. Si estás utilizando `PDO` debes asegurarte de que el valor de retorno de la función `conectar` devuelva `new PDO($dsn, "usuario", "contraseña");`.

Comment: Por otra parte, observo que tienes la línea `$stmt->close()` después de `return`. Recuerda, que todo lo que se defina después de `return` no se ejecuta. En tal caso, sería preferible almacenar en una variable `$dato = $stmt->fetch();` y devolverlo y pasarlo como valor de retorno: `return $dato;` si va a utilizar `$stmt->close();`.

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/408591/29967) se aborda la causa de este problema. Deberás corregir en tu código todas las llamadas del tipo `Clase::metodo()` cuando `metodo` sea estático, pero el contexto desde el cual llames a `metodo` no sea estático o vicerversa.

Comment: Gracias a todos ya logre resolverlo ... thanks!!